# How to run automated rsync using ssh2

Tags: ssh, passwords, rsync

i am trying to setup rsync between two machines over ssh2 protocol. 
Earlier we used ssh1 for automated rsync without any passphrase, but recently we migrated to ssh2 and running rsync with ssh2 prompts for passphrase.

I generated a new SSH2-RSA key and that too without passphrase, but it still asks me for the passphrase.Here is the command that i run for ssh
/usr/bin/ssh -2 -i /usr/local/www-rsync-key fsuser@xyz

What steps do you have to do to get an ssh2 key with a null password to work?  I'm guessing there are certain settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config you have to set, but I can't figure out what!

Comment: shouldn't this be on superuser.com?

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/103722/ssh-completly-disabling-password-authentication) appeared on Superuser, discussing the topic of ssh without a password.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting prompted for a password, check that you've added the public key to the correct file on the far side (could be authorized_keys2 now), and that the directory permissions are correct (.ssh and its contents shouldn't have any group or world permissions set).

Comment: The logs on the destination machine will say if there is a problem with permissions on the .ssh directory or files.

Comment: Agreed, but people don't always check them...  You can also enable verbose mode to show the negotiation sequence (ssh -v).